change XML declaration to single quote
I have below incoming xml format and for this input XML I just need to add soap envelope.
Input xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:msg
    xmlns:p="http://.xml.invoice.com">
    <access>
        <NAME>ABC</NAME>
    </access>
    <requestBody>
        <content>test message</content>
    </requestBody>
</p:msg>

with below simple xslt code i am able to add soap envelope but this declaration  needs to be in single quote    
XSLT code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <!-- Template to match the root of the XML document -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- Start of SOAP Envelope -->
        <soapenv:Envelope
            xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:p="http://.xml.invoice.com">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <!-- SOAP Body -->
            <soapenv:Body>
                <!-- Copy the original XML payload into the Body -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="/*"/>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

could you pleas help me if there is any way to change xml declaration from single quote to double quote.
Expected output (xml version and encoding should be in single quote.)
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:p="http://.xml.invoice.com">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <p:msg>
            <access>
                <NAME>ABC</NAME>
            </access>
            <requestBody>
                <content>test message</content>
            </requestBody>
        </p:msg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>


Show us the exact result you want to create.

@MartinHonnenI have added the expected output in same question.

Which XSLT processor you use?

The commercial versions of Saxon (ie. PE and EE) have an extension serialization attribute saxon:single-quotes="yes" but it looks as if it doesn't change the quote character of the XML declaration, only the one used for attributes of XML elements. On the .NET platform there is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter.quotechar?view=net-9.0#system-xml-xmltextwriter-quotechar but I haven't tested whether using that also affects the XML declaration. So it might be difficult to achieve that with the available tools. Why do you need that anyway?

For .NET I have now tested that using an XmlTextWriter with QuoteChar set to a single quote (e.g. var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(...);xmlWriter.QuoteChar = '\'';) indeed writes the pseudo attributes of the XML declaration with single quotes; note, however, that all attribute values that way are also written out with single quotes as the delimiter.

This shouldn't be necessary but if you must have it, you could use a hack like this:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
</xsl:text>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:p="http://.xml.invoice.com">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

This is assuming your processor supports disable-output-escaping.

Thanks for your response. I have asked the 3rd party if these double quotes make any difference so their application is able to accept with double quotes. my application not supporting  disable-output-escaping

You should also ask them if you can omit the XML declaration altogether. Note that the XML specification states that the declaration is optional. It also expressly allows the declaration to use either quotes or apostrophes - so if their parser chokes on it, it's their fault.

Hi, There is a change in requirement to add P prefixes in msg node. I have edited same question could you please check and suggest.

This has nothing to do with your original problem. I have rolled back your question to what it was when I answered it. Please ask a new question with your new requirement (and only your new requirement).

Sure, I I am able to achieve other requirement also. Thank you very much for your inputs.
